# Рут доступ к методам VUE 3

Tags: vue.js

Всем привет. Во второй версии VUE 2 я использовал такую команду this.$root.$refs.Название и вставлял его в created компонента. И с этого момента мог получить доступ к его методам и переменным из других компонентов. Щас перешел на Vue 3 и выдает ошибку. Походу не поддерживается. Какая есть альтернатива кто знает?  Раньше делал так и работало:

```
export default{
 data: () => ({
     page:1,
   }),

   created() { 
          this.$root.$refs.mycomponent= this; 
    },

    methods:{
     nextPage($i){
              this.page=$i;
          }
   },
}
```

или может еще другой способ есть чтобы получить доступ к методам и переменным друг другу совершенно разным компонентам?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очевидно, это [проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy).

> или может еще другой способ есть чтобы получить доступ к методам и переменным друг другу совершенно разным компонентам?

Безусловно, такие способы есть. Более того, практически любой другой способ будет являться предпочтительным, потому что записывать свойства в рут так, как это делаете вы - это костыль и совершенно не Vue-way.

Варианты следующие:

1. Для Vue 2 был такой паттерн как [EventBus](https://monsterlessons.com/project/lessons/eventbus-v-vuejs). Создавался отдельный компонент который встраивался в другие как дочерний и служил только для выбрасывания событий на нем, чтобы один компонент мог это событие инициировать, а другой на него подписаться.
2. Во Vue 3 необходимость в EventBus отпала в виду того, что реактивность была вынесена из ядра в отдельные методы. Теперь стало возможно определить реактивную переменную как `export const myVar = ref()`, импортировать ее буквально куда угодно и не потерять при этом реактивность.
3. [provide-inject](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html). Стандартный способ работы с компонентами неопределенного уровня вложенности (зачастую, рекурсивных компонентов). Родительский компонент предоставляет (`provide`s) какое-то реактивное значение, любой дочерний компонент включает (`inject`s) его в себя (при необходимости).
4. Более системным подходом будет использование какой-нибудь стейт-менеджмент библиотеки. Их множество различных форматов, но есть официальные реализации Flux-архитектуры, такие как [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) и [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/) (предпочтительно). По сути, вы просто создаете некое глобальное хранилище, значения в котором реактивны и доступ к ним можно получить из любого компонента в приложении (и даже вне компонентов, если речь идет о Pinia).

В целом советую почитать [вот это](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html).

Comment: Спасибо за такую инфу, очень полезно. Я последовал примеру из ссылки. Хотел использовать  reactive Vue 3 , но почему-то мне выдает ошибку Uncaught ReferenceError: reactive is not defined хотя VUE 3 точно подключен через CDN. Может эта функция  reactive не работает через CDN?     Вот ссылка источника откуда я это взял  https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#simple-state-management-with-reactivity-api

Comment: @porshen.vip скорее всего она либо идет из отдельного пакета, либо занеймспейшена под чем-то вроде `Vue.reactive()` или т.п. Через CDN со вью не работал, поэтому точно сказать не могу, можете задать отдельный вопрос, думаю, кто-нибудь подскажет.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо.